# Turning Object with SkSpriteNode

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, skspritenode

I have an image named "Ghost" and it moves throughout the screen. I want to have the SpriteNode constantly turning without being pressed on.

```
Ghost = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ghost1")
    Ghost.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    Ghost.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 - Ghost.frame.width, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    Ghost.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Ghost.frame.height / 1.4)
    Ghost.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ghost
    Ghost.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ground | PhysicsCatagory.Wall
    Ghost.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ground | PhysicsCatagory.Wall | PhysicsCatagory.Score
    Ghost.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Ghost.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    Ghost.zPosition = 2

    self.addChild(Ghost)
```

I have looked for some answers on Stack Overflow but I can't seem to find any one with this same question, please help.

Comment: By turning do you mean rotating?

Comment: @Nik Yes, I want it to endlessly rotate once the GameScene loads in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply a force of an angular type, so as to rotate the body, and turn off damping so it continues to rotate forever:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417775-applyangularimpulse

### Or, apply torque:

Firstly, make sure it’s able to rotate by setting this to true:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519986-allowsrotation

Make sure there’s no angular damping so that it doesn’t slow in rotation rate:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519913-angulardamping

Now make it spin by applying a torque:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519588-applytorque

### Or, set a spin rate:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519766-angularvelocity

Comment: only "problem" with this approach is if you have a physics world, other physics could destroy the rotation, and needs to reset.  You will need to assess this problem  on a case by case basis to determine if this answer or Nik answer is what you need (Nik answer will spin forever regardless of physics world, but physics world can still affect the results until physics wear off,  then it will go back to normal forever state)

Answer (score 3):

To have the SKSpriteNode constantly rotating, add this to wherever you want to start the rotating:

```
let rotate = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2.0, duration: 2)
Ghost.run(SKAction.repeatForever(rotate), withKey: "rotateGhost")
```

To rotate in the opposite direction, change `CGFloat.pi` to `-CGFloat.pi`

You can fidget with the duration to change the duration for a complete rotation.

If you wish to remove the action, call:

```
removeAction(forKey: "rotateGhost")
```

Or you can just pause the action instead.

Comment: I get an error that says "Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Int'

Comment: No, it says,  "Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double'" it is pointing at the *

Comment: I changed it a bit. Try it now