# How to make a Sprite node spin when a user taps the screen? Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nodes, skspritenode

**The result Im looking to achieve**: I have a node that is pretty much a bicycle wheel with spokes. When the user tapes the screen, I would like the wheel to not only bounce, but to spin as well with each tap.

**What I have now**: The node currently bounces when the user taps the screen, just as it should. However it does not spin.

I am still learning swift, so any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

**Code**:

```
    wheelNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "wheel")
    wheelNode.zPosition = 1
    wheelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    wheelNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: wheelNode.size.width / 0.70)
    wheelNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    wheelNode.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true

    self.addChild(wheelNode)

override func touchesBegan(_ _touches: Set<UITouch> , with event: UIEvent?) {
    if gameOver == false {

    self.wheelNode.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    self.wheelNode.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 5, dy: 25))

    }

}
```

Comment: try using somehing like `SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat ,duration: TimeInterval)`. Where you can set how much you want it rotate (with angle) and how much it should last

Comment: to run it just use: `run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat ,duration: TimeInterval))`

Comment: Hi @Ergo, thank you for your response! I assume that the SKAction will go outside of the touchesBegan function? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have the SKSpriteNode rotating, add this to `touchesBegan`:

```
wheelNode.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2.0, duration: 2)), withKey: "rotateWheel")
```

To rotate in the opposite direction, change `CGFloat.pi` to `-CGFloat.pi`

You can fidget with the duration to change the duration for a complete rotation.

In `touchesEnded`, to stop the action, call:

```
removeAction(forKey: "rotateWheel")
```

This way, the wheels rotation doesn't get affected by the physics world. If you want a different way to do the rotating, take a look at this link (and read the comment from @Knight0fDragon): https://stackoverflow.com/a/39779986/6728196

The logic would still be the same however. In that you need to start the rotating in `touchesBegan` then end/stop it in `touchesEnded`.

Comment: Hi @Nik, the code / answer you provided worked. I do have a related question for you while we're still on this topic. What would I need to add or change in order to have the wheelNode spin only when the user taps the screen? Say the user tapped the screen once, what would I need to do in order for the wheel to spin when screen is tapped, then gradually slow down to a stop? That is something that I was just curious about.

Comment: @P.Dane Hmm... I'm not actually sure. You couldn't use the SKAction method though, because it uses repeat forever. Using one of the other methods provided in the link, you would just have to make it so your physicsworld makes the wheel slow down. If you want, try that on your own, then open a question about it

Answer (score 3):

add the following line in the touchesBegan method:

```
self.wheelNode.physicsBody?.applyAngularImpulse(5)
```

Than you have a rotation which is consistent to the rest of your physics based game.